# Aptana: How can you link files with include(), require() etc like you can in Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, aptana, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver, if you use include() etc, it recognises them as resources and you can then flick between them as Dreamweaver creates 'tabs' for them at the top of the page (and other resources linked from that file, e.g. javascripts etc). How can you at least make Aptana acknowledge an outside resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I'm using Netbeans, but before this I also used Aptana 2.

In Aptana 2 it worked for me by doing this:

1. Right click on the project and select "Properties"
2. Switch to the project natures
3. Select *web* as primary nature.
4. also check *php* as project nature
5. press CTRL and move the mouse over the path / require, it should be clickable now

Maybe you have to restart Aptana.
If this does not work, try to set php as primary nature. (one of this settings worked for me)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - perhaps I'm being thick, but following these instructions doesn't seem to make any difference...!

Comment: Do you press Ctrl while you move the mouse over the path / require?

Comment: The docs page on 'Attaching PHP Resources' is useful for Aptana Studio 3 users: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/PHP+Development#PHPDevelopment-AttachingPHPResources